# Load a frame with html source in ASP.net

Tags: html, asp.net, frame

In asp.net website page i have a frame. I want to load the frame with a html page. But not by specifying frame source as html file,instead by using html source. The source may be varying and i will be fetching it from my database.

So how to load a frame with html source in ASP.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the HTML document as a `data:` scheme URI and set it as the `src` to the frame.

Comment: <iframe id="frm1"  src="data:text/html,<p align="center">Some HTML</p>"> wont work. bcoz it contains " in it(in html source). how to handle it?

Comment: The normal way you include a quote character in an attribute value delimited with quotes. You use the character reference `&quot;`.

Answer (score 0):

> The source may be varying and i will be fetching it from my database.

Then link the frame to a page that pulls and prints the HTML, giving the primary key as query string parameter.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get what you told. I want to load frame source with a source which is stored in database.

Comment: Make the frame like `<iframe src="LoadHtml.aspx?ID=42"></iframe>` and in `LoadHtml.aspx` you read the HTML for that ID from the database and output it.